# React/D3: Render graph from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, render

I am trying to pass data from a parent component to a child and have the child render it to the screen.  The rendering is linked to a submit button. Also, on the submit button I'm passing the data (or I think I am) to the child to render but nothing shows up on the screen.

From inside the return function nested in the Parent:

```
{this.state.submit && <Graph width={400} height={220} nodes={this.data}/>}
```

The child component:

```
import './graph.css';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Calendar from '../Calendar/index';

class Graph extends Component {

    render() {

        return(

            <div className="Graph">

            <p>{this.props.nodes}</p>
            </div>

        )//return

    }//render
}

export default Graph;
```

Populate Data

```
 populate(){
        const {data:{loading, error, action}} = this.props;
        console.log(this.props);
        if(loading) {
            return <option disabled>Loading...</option>;
          }else if (error){
            return<p>Error!</p>;
          }
          return (
            <Item.Group divided>
              {action.map(action =>
                <div>
                  <ul>
                  <li>{action.action}</li>
                  <li>{action.timestamp}</li>
                  <ul>
                  {action.object.map( (obj) => {
                    return (<li>{obj.filename}</li>)
                  })}
                  </ul>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              )}
              </Item.Group>

            );
          }
```

Comment: Does this.props.nodes have any data when you console log it?

Comment: No, its undefined. That does not make any sense. I thought, this sent it out, `<Graph width={400} height={220} nodes={this.data}/>`?

Comment: Can you post the code in the parent function in which `this.data` is being populated?

Comment: Are you sure its {this.data} or {this.state.data} ? The state usually has data right? Just speculating. Would need to see the whole code of the parent.

Comment: Is the syntax right for passing data to the child, Graph?

Comment: Yes the syntax is correct, you need to post the entire parent code. There isn't enough here to help you. Based on what you've said, its probably undefined in the parent.